# zpool mount issues on boot

Tags: debian, xen, zfs

Looking for help with errors I'm encountering with ZFS.

Firstly, the main issue is that I can't get my zpool to mount at boot, but there are obviously other problems I would like to sort out (see `dmesg` and bootlog below). I use the system as a media server and torrent box.

**NOTE:** Just to be clear I will detail my system specs and setup:

OK I'm using an OpenMediaVault Virtual machine inside a Xen host (it runs as a domu). The OMV version is 0.5.57(Sardaukar) and this runs a linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 kernel. attached to this vm is a raidz1 array (4 disks) that are physically attached to a highpoint rocketraid 2720 pci card (this card is passed through to the VM)

Here are both my boot log and dmesg outputs. (any help would be much appreciated as I have only limited experience with linux):

- [dmesg via pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Ayca1URm)
- [boot log via pastebin](http://pastebin.com/KxE7s2Bd)

Comment: Can you mount it manually? What is the output to `zfs get mountpoint <zfs file system>`?

Comment: Yes I can mount it manually but I have to import the pool first. As far as i can tell it will not auto import upon boot and hence it will not mount. I have read around a bit I think it may be a problem with fstab entries?? but I'm not game to mess with that. to answer your question the output is: `code` NAME       PROPERTY    VALUE           SOURCE
MegaZPool  mountpoint  /mnt/MegaZPool  local

Comment: I don't know about ZFS in Debain, but in Solaris, you no longer use /etc/fstab for ZFS file systems (or in Solaris' case /etc/vfstab). To set the mount points, use `zfs set mountpoint=<mount point> zpool`, e.g. `zfs set mountpoint=/export/new_mount mypool`